# Why is this style not being added to my radio button?

Tags: jquery, html, css, radio-button

I'm validating that part of my form is complete before submission and trying to add a class that will outline the radio button in red if it hasn't been selected. I'm triggering the alert so I know it's not checked but the style fails to get set.  Any idea what I'm missing?

Here is my current code:

CSS:

```
.form_error {
    border-color: #ee5f5b;
}
```

JQuery:

```
        for (i=1;i<4;i++) {

            if (!$('input[name=answer'+i+']:checked').val()) {
                alert("Not checked");
                $("#question_answer"+i).addClass("form_error");
            }
        }
```

HTML:

```
<td>
    <input type="radio" id="question_answer1" name="answer1" value="1" >Yes
    <input type="radio" id="question_answer1" name="answer1" value="0" >No
</td>
```

Comment: As an aside, form controls are not tabular data...

Comment: @danwellman — They *could* be, although usually aren't.

Comment: `<label>` elements are really useful, as well as helping screen readers they provide decent sized click targets for mouse users.

Comment: @Quentin - When could they be? They certainly aren't in this case.

Comment: @danwellman — Off the top of my head: `<th>Title <th>Author <th>Have you read this book?`

Comment: Yes/No states are likely better represented by a checkbox than a pair of radio buttons too.

Comment: @danwellman e.g. when you have rows of data, say users, and a column, say "Subscribed".

Comment: @Quentin I would still argue that although Title and Author are tabular, the question of whether or not the book has been read remains nontabular. So at best the table will be a mix of tabular and nontabular data. Is this bad? I guess it's debatable...Agree with your statement re checkbox over 2 radios though ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could the issue be that the two inputs have the same ID attribute? As they are radio buttons it's ok for them to share a name but elements should never share an ID.

Comment: No. Error recovery would usually cause the border to be applied to the first button with that ID. (So while that is *an* issue, it isn't *the* issue)

Comment: That was the issue.  I wrapped the two radios in a div tag and added the style to that. Thanks!

Comment: @Paul — Umm, if you had to style a different element, then it wasn't having duplicate ids that solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

It is, you just can't tell because most browsers [don't render radio buttons with borders](http://jsfiddle.net/DtxnF/).

Answer (score 2):

As others have stated, it may have to do with the duplicate `id` values.  But there's no sense selecting the same elements using 2 different selectors anyway.  Once you figure out the original problem, I suggest trying something like this:

```
for ( i = 1 ; i < 4 ; i++ ) {

  $( "input[name='answer" + i + "']" ).not( ":checked" ).toggleClass( "form_error", true );

}
// for
```